# UITableViewDataSource doesn't get invoked

Tags: swift, ios7

I am trying to learn swift which is also my first programming language. I am trying learn by creating an app with table view in it. I have added a table view and table cell(myCell as identifier). Table cell in turn has labels and text field. Also the background color of the table cell is yellow.

The view controller which encapsulates all this is hooked to class showDetailViewController as show below.

```
class showDetailViewController:UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //UITableViewDataSource
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell: TaskCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as TaskCell
        return cell
    }

    //UITableViewDelegate
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }

}
```

When I run my application I expect to see my cell replicated 5 times (as number of cells in section returns 5) in table view but upon debug I realized that the no tableview delegate class get invoked and hence the issue.

Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Thanks,
Dev

Comment: where did you add the UITableView to the UIViewController. Was it in the interface builder?

Comment: Where is the tableView?

Comment: Yes via Interface builder.

Comment: did you add the tableView as an IBOutlet?

Comment: I think it's because showDetailViewController is not a table view, so your cellForRowAtIndexPath method is not called. You can change your class to subclass UITableViewController instead of generic UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

Add the tableView as an IBOutlet.Then you should set tableView's datasource to viewController. `self.tableView.dataSource = self`. You can also set tableView's dataSource in Interface bulider.